# How to disable smoothing of images in Fabric.js when toDataUrl() is called?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, todataurl

Is it possible to disable smoothing of images within the canvas of Fabric.js when I export the canvas with [toDataUrl()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toDataURL)? I'm using version 3.6.2.

I have created the canvas with this code:

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-1', {
    imageSmoothingEnabled: false
});
```

[imageSmoothingEnabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) turns off the smoothing in the canvas. However, when I call `toDataUrl()` with an multiplier and I show the result in an img, the smoothing is still there and it was also multiplied.

```
const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', multiplier: 3});
$imgageElement.attr('src', dataUrl); //jQuery
```

What do I have to do so that I get exactly what is displayed in the canvas?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robsch/87pxdLaw/). And here is [report](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/6194), since I think it is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround seems to be overriding [toCanvasElement](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/19230c29020671ebe31405f08e7d8cc3b27dfe1c/src/mixins/canvas_dataurl_exporter.mixin.js#L59) with:

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-1', {
    imageSmoothingEnabled: false
});

canvas.toCanvasElement = function (multiplier, cropping) {
    multiplier               = multiplier || 1;
    cropping                 = cropping || {};
    var scaledWidth          = (cropping.width || this.width) * multiplier,
        scaledHeight         = (cropping.height || this.height) * multiplier,
        zoom                 = this.getZoom(),
        originalWidth        = this.width,
        originalHeight       = this.height,
        newZoom              = zoom * multiplier,
        vp                   = this.viewportTransform,
        translateX           = (vp[4] - (cropping.left || 0)) * multiplier,
        translateY           = (vp[5] - (cropping.top || 0)) * multiplier,
        originalInteractive  = this.interactive,
        newVp                = [newZoom, 0, 0, newZoom, translateX, translateY],
        originalRetina       = this.enableRetinaScaling,
        canvasEl             = fabric.util.createCanvasElement(),
        originalContextTop   = this.contextTop;
    canvasEl.width           = scaledWidth;
    canvasEl.height          = scaledHeight;
    this.contextTop          = null;
    this.enableRetinaScaling = false;
    this.interactive         = false;
    this.viewportTransform   = newVp;
    this.width               = scaledWidth;
    this.height              = scaledHeight;
    this.calcViewportBoundaries();
    var ctx                   = canvasEl.getContext('2d');    // replaced
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;                        // this.renderCanvas(canvasEl.getContext('2d'), this._objects);
    this.renderCanvas(ctx, this._objects);                    // with these 3 lines
    this.viewportTransform = vp;
    this.width             = originalWidth;
    this.height            = originalHeight;
    this.calcViewportBoundaries();
    this.interactive         = originalInteractive;
    this.enableRetinaScaling = originalRetina;
    this.contextTop          = originalContextTop;
    return canvasEl;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't completely resolve your problem, but you can somehow make it less evident using a [Resize filter](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.filters.Resize.html):

```js
var img = new fabric.Image(img, {
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  angle: 5,
  zoom: 3,
  objectCaching: false
});
img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Resize({
    resizeType: 'sliceHack',
    scaleX: 4,
    scaleY: 4
  }));
  img.applyFilters();

img.scale(4);

canvas.add(img);
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67xbygzt/2/).

Comment: Interesting... Wondering what happens here, as it seems that the Resize filter doesn't resize the image itself. It also seems that it doesn't matter which resizeType is used.